# Traefik 2.4 + LetsEncrypt - example fails to obtain ACME certificate for domain

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, lets-encrypt

I am new to traefik and I'am trying to run the example in https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-http/ . I got stuck on the following problem:

```
traefik    | time="2021-06-02T08:36:49Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"www.babauno.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the dooblem:\n[www.babauno.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://www.babauno.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/7wbLcfOrule="Host(`www.babauno.com`)" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=whoami@docker
```

Some more info: - I am using docker container on EC2 AWS (ubuntu 18.04 LTS). The domain has an "A" record defined in Route 53. Elastic (fixed) IP address defined.

I am stuck on this for days now and really appreciate any feedback/hint that can help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: Have you verified if port 80 is accessible? In AWS console, add an inbound rule to allow access to port 80. You can create this rule under the "Security Groups" which your EC2 instance is part of.